# Overriding Joomla Admin Template

Tags: php, templates, joomla, overriding, administrator

I have created minor Joomla template overrides before. I just read through their documentation again here: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides, but I can't find if there's a way to override the admin template. Let's say I want to override the default ISIS template. Where would I put the override files if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template overrides for the backend template work exactly the same as they do for the frontend.

You simply need to follow the same process as described in [Understanding Output Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides), but instead, add your overrides to:

```
administrator/templates/isis/html
```

Hope this helps